# The solution of Poisson's equation

Tags: poissons-equation, laplacian

From Evan's book, we know that, in $R^n$, the function $u$ defined as
$$ u(x):=\int_{R^n}\Phi(y)f(x-y)dy,$$
where $f\in C^2(R^n)$ and $\Phi$ is the fundamental solutions of Laplace equation. Then we have $u\in C^2(R^n)$ as well and also we have $-\triangle u = f$.

However, my professor in addition comments that "it's possible to extend the theorem to more general $f$. For example, if $f$ is integrable, and Holder continuous, then
$$ u(x)=\int_{R^n}\Phi(y)f(x-y)dy,$$
satisfies $-\triangle u = f$, at least for $n\geq 3$.

I can not even prove that $u\in C^2(R^n)$, not to mention that $-\triangle u =f$... Help is very appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

It is true that $f$ does not need to be so smooth, and by using the fact that $-\Delta \Phi(x)=\delta_{0}$ i.e. the dirac delta function we may calculate $$-\Delta u(x)=\int_{\Bbb R^n}-\Delta_{x}\Phi(x-y)f(y)\,dy=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\delta_{x}f(y)\,dy=f(x).$$

Comment: This is actually from evans book :) see page 25

Comment: I read something similar from Evan's book. However, I can not buy it because the prove of $-\triangle \Phi(x)=\delta_0$ is highly depends on the smoothness of $f$. Without $f$ is smooth, I don't know how to prove $-\triangle \Phi(x)=\delta_0$. Also, what about $f$ be integrable and Holder continuous? what they do here? Thx!

Comment: @user124358 I imagine the integrability helps to show that $\int_{\Bbb R^n}\delta_{x}f(y)dy=f(x)$, since say there was some $x_0\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $f$ was not integrable at such $x_0$ then I don't believe this would hold

Comment: @user124358, and Evans's book mentions the book of Gilbarg-Trudinger as reference, where a proof can be found on page 54-56 (2nd edition).

Comment: @andre, Thx a lot! Looks like it is not a trivial proof. I will look at it. Thx again!